# How to get a pending transaction? I am using python with web3py

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, python, pending-transactions

I am using the URL "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/key".
But I can't get a pending transaction.
This is my code.

`pendingTransaction = web3.eth.filter('pending')`

I had an error like this.

`The method eth_newPendingTransactionFilter does not exist/is not available.`

What reason this error?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get pending transactions using the standard Infura endpoint. I recommend to use [chainstack.com](https://chainstack.com/), it's free and it works.

Then you can use web3.py to get the pending transactions. I have a repo about this [here](https://github.com/soos3d/Retrive-and-display-pending-transactions-Web3.py) if you want to check it out.
But the main code is this:

```
# retrive pending transactions hash
pending_tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
pending_tx = pending_tx_filter.get_new_entries()     

# loop through the list of transcations and displays the tx hash
for hash in pending_tx:
    print('Hash of a Pending Transaction:' , web3.toHex(hash))
```

Answer (score 0):

Infura does not provide stateful API methods, like creating filters. A filter would need to maintain a state on the server side.

Depending on the use case

- Subscribe to live events via WebSockets
- Do something like a [polling loop](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events) that maintains the state of the latest fetch on the client side
- [Don't use Infura, but your own Ethereum node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) to get access to the all API methods

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I received a result like this. `Filter for 0x6820`. Could you get transaction data from this data?

Comment: See `get_new_entries` and `get_all_entries` https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#web3.utils.filters.Filter.get_new_entries